# function with different standard given arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments, shortcut

first to mention, my code works, I just feel, I could do it more efficient. But how?

I have  a routine with (optional and standard given) arguments:

```
def read(fpath = 'C:', fname = 'text.txt')
```

Later I call this function and case by case different arguments for the shown function:

```
def get(index, path=None, name=None):
    if path == None:
        if name == None:
            elements = read()
        else:
            elements = read(fname=name)
    else:
        if name == None:
            elements = read(fpath=path)
        else:
            elements = read(fpath=path,fname=name)
```

How can I write it shorter without losing clarity of code?

Thank you.

*PS: Is my first question, if I missed a rule, please correct me. I'm learning.*

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the definition of `read` to use the same arguments' names, then you can call it directly.

```
def read(path=None, name=None):
    print(path)
    print(name)
    return 'something usefull'

def get(index, **kwargs):
    elements = read(**kwargs)

get(0, path='a path', name='a name')

# a path
# a name
```

Instead of `path=None, name=None` you can of course provide actual default values in `read`'s definition (unless they are mutable).

Comment: thank you, now I get how and why the **kwargs is useful!

Answer (score 1):

You could work with a dictionary and use keyword parameters:

```
def get(index, path = None, name = None):
    kwargs = {}
    if path is not None:
        kwargs['path'] = path
    if name is not None:
        kwargs['name'] = name
    elements = read(**kwargs)
```

Or if you simply want to filter out `None`s for all parameters:

```
def get(index, path = None, name = None):
    kwargs = dict(path = path, name = name)
    elements = read(**{k:v for k,v in kwargs.items() if v is not None})
```

Nevertheless I wonder whether it wouldn't be better, if you *communicate the default values to the user* by *using the same default values*. Since a user will notice *weird behavior*. So my advice would be to use:

```
def read(index, fpath = 'C:', fname = 'text.txt'):
    elements = read(fpath=fpath,fname=fname)
```

Since now a user can see from the type signature what will happen if he/she does not provide a certain parameter. You can also pass the `**kwargs` in which case the arguments provided to `get` are (with except of `index` here), passed to `read(..)`:

```
def get(index, **kwargs):
    elements = read(**kwargs)
```

Comment: thank you. This is a nice way of solving it! I like the examples. Helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **kwargs over here.

**kwargs allows you to pass keyworded variable length of arguments to a function. You should use **kwargs if you want to handle named arguments in a function. Here is an example:

```
def greet_me(**kwargs):
    if kwargs is not None:
        for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            print "%s == %s" %(key,value)
```

Output:

> greet_me(name="yasoob")
>   name == yasoob